# ¿Cómo podría enrutar de manera automática los archivos de una carpeta en REACT?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, react-navigation

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto personal, menús para restaurantes. Anteriormente estaba usando HTML y CSS, pero ahora me gustaría comenzar con una app en react, lo que estoy intentando es enrutar automáticamente todos los menús que tenga una carpeta determinada, para que solo con el enlace me muestre el menú de ese restaut

```js
function App() {

  return (
    <>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Inicio/>}>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/menus" element={<Menus/>}>
          
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Yo al menos no entiendo bien que es lo que quieres. No se a que te refieres con carpetas. Por lo general en las rutas se pone una page, que no es mas que un contenedor para componentes

Comment: Quiero que me agregue las rutas de forma automática, para no tener que hacerlo manual